# Reach redux state from static function

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a React Native application where I have a class which name is Helpers. These are a set of application related static helper function. Mostly I call them like `Helpers.functionName()`. What is the best way to reach the redux store from this static method? I want to modify it and read it.

I have the Helpers like this:

```
class Helpers extends Component {
  static getState(){
    return state;
  }
}
```

I tried to use the connect, but inside the getState function the this.props is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to pass store as argument to each static function that requires it. Or you could make store global variable and access it as such.

I would hesitate though to describe any of those ways as best, or use any other positive adjective for that matter. Redux can be used in many ways, but I think intention was to discourage store access as global.

Also note that changing the store directly from your helper functions is a whole another level of no-no. Intention of redux is that only reducer functions change state in response to dispatched actions.

Lastly, is Helpers really a component that you are using, or just container for bunch of static functions? If later, than it is probably misleading to derive it from Component.

Comment: I created as a global variable, thanks. Yes it is just a bunsh of static method.

Answer (score 2):

If you used the `Provider` component, so you can access to the redux store (and by consequence to the state of your store), using the `context` API provided by React.

In order to expose the context, you have to define the `contextTypes` inside your `Helpers` components.

```
static contextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object
}
```

After that, inside your component you can read the store from `this.context`